# What is the symbol to start printing called?

Tags: buttons, icons, terminology

What is a common term used to describe the symbol that is used on printers, photocopier and fax machines to start printing? It is square standing on one of its corners with a vertical line inside almost connecting the top and the bottom corner but with some space around. It usually appears on a big green button.

[image: Start button]

The only description I could find is at http://www.baddesigns.com/copier.html, calling it “the line in the diamond”. I was however unable to find any name whatsoever. Canon uses this symbol on some of its Pixma line printers ([example](https://ij.manual.canon/ij/webmanual/Manual/All/MG3600%20series/EN/BG/bg-component1400.html)), but only an icon is used to reference the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This symbol is listed as IEC 60417-5104 and is called **Start [of action]** in the [ISO/IEC 13251 collection](https://cdn.standards.iteh.ai/samples/74344/171d07caa62a48c691bd9070f8a5a60c/ISO-IEC-13251-2019.pdf) of office symbols. It is commonly swapped with a line inside a circle today.